# TImeout Issue on adding user to the custom mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Mongodb 3.2.1 and I  executed the mongodb copydatabase command to clone the existing db having user roles.I am not able to find the same user and roles to copied db.When I tried to add new user I am getting the below error.

```
    Error: timed out while waiting for user authentication to replicate - database will not be fully secured until replication finishes :
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1221:1
@(shell):1:1

db.createUser(
          {
          user: "AAAAA",
          pwd: "AAAAAA",
          roles: ["dbOwner", "read"]
          })
```

My secondarydb status

```
                "state" : 3,
                "stateStr" : "RECOVERING",
                "uptime" : 153861,
```

My Mongodb secondary db was in recovering state.Is this why the addUser fails?.can anyone help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the secondarydb has to be fully available for the query to be propagated within the entire replica set.

I had a similar issue, in which I had turned off one of my slaves, when I turned it back on and re-run the query, it worked.

Else, you will need to deregister the secondarydb from the replicaset.